# Updating table based on global substring match via IF statement or CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, date

I have hundreds of thousands of rows with four date columns that were imported as such:

```
Mon Nov 14 14:52:46 PST 2011
Fri Nov 04 07:50:21 PDT 2011
Thu Dec 01 00:00:00 PST 2011
```

There are three months: Nov, Dec, Jan.  I want my new date format saved to new columns in this format:

> 11-14-2011, 11-04-2011, 12-01-2011 and so on....

I'm able to do this via an update statement that matches the substring month name and replaces it with the matching numeric.  So I can do it with something like this:

```
UPDATE tabel 
   set col1 = REPLACE(substring(col2, 5,3) 'Nov', 11)
```

And it works for the first month I run.  But when I then add Dec and Jan, then it only works for those months and resets the string for the three letter months in all the other rows I just did.

I don't know how to execute this UPDATE and REPLACE command in the right way so it matches all three months in the database and then writes out the new format to the new column like I want.  I'm a bit new to T-SQL and so far I'm overwhelmed with the amount of documentation out there.  I've tried putting all three months into a series of UPDATE statements and that did not work.  I think it needs to go row by row, test a condition and then execute the update if it matches.

Maybe like this:

```
IF @dateColSubString = 'Jan' Then
   UPDATE table
         set newDateCol = REPLACE(substring(col2, 5,3) 'Jan', 01) + '-2012'
   COMMIT
IF @dateColSubString = 'Dec' Then
   UPDATE table
         set newDateCol = REPLACE(substring(col2, 5,3) 'Dec', 12) + '-2011'
   COMMIT
```

to make values like this in the new column '01-2011'  and then have those not be reset to there old values when I run the same update request for 'Nov' and then 'Dec' to change those strings.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Is newDateCol a text (varchar/nvarchar) column? If so, have you considered converting it to a datetime datatype, like datetimeoffset: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx ?

Comment: It is a varchar and I did consider converting, but until Oleg's answer below, I didn't know the best way to go about it.  There are so many different approaches to take in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and do whatever you want with your datetime

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(str varchar(100))
INSERT @t
VALUES('Mon Nov 14 14:52:46 PST 2011'),('Fri Nov 04 07:50:21 PDT 2011'),('Thu Dec 01 00:00:00 PST 2011')

SELECT 
    CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, CAST(SUBSTRING(str, 5, 6) +' '+RIGHT(str, 4) AS DATETIME)) AS VARCHAR) +'-'+ RIGHT(str, 4),
    CAST(SUBSTRING(str, 5, 6) +' '+RIGHT(str, 4) AS DATETIME),
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(SUBSTRING(str, 5, 6) +' '+RIGHT(str, 4) AS DATETIME), 110)
FROM @t
```

In your case, a suppose, it is like this - you only have to choose which result is more suitable for you and adopt the corresponding query row:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, CAST(SUBSTRING(order_send, 5, 6) +' '+RIGHT(order_send, 4) AS DATETIME)) AS VARCHAR) +'-'+ RIGHT(order_send, 4),
    CAST(SUBSTRING(order_send, 5, 6) +' '+RIGHT(order_send, 4) AS DATETIME),
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(SUBSTRING(order_send, 5, 6) +' '+RIGHT(order_send, 4) AS DATETIME), 110)
FROM YourTableName
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how do I do this for a table consisting of hundreds of rows in that long string format?  

I'm trying to figure out how to write this line to work on my table for everything:

INSERT @t
VALUES('Mon Nov 14 14:52:46 PST 2011'),('Fri Nov 04 07:50:21 PDT 2011'),('Thu Dec 01 00:00:00 PST 2011')

When one of the columns is named, order_sent, let's say....

Comment: My insert was only for demonstration on your data. You may change in the last select statement the name of table to yours and the name of column 'str' to your 'order_send'. I'll update the answer

Comment: Thank you.  i will try and run your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If you are fine with losing the timezone information, you could simply remove the day of week and time zone parts and convert the resulting string to `datetime` using simple `CAST` or `CONVERT`, like this:

```
;
WITH StringDates (OldDateCol) AS (
  SELECT 'Mon Nov 14 14:52:46 PST 2011' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Fri Nov 04 07:50:21 PDT 2011' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Thu Dec 01 00:00:00 PST 2011'
)
SELECT
  OldDateCol,
  NewDateCol = CAST(SUBSTRING(STUFF(OldDateCol, 21, 4, ''), 5, 99) AS datetime)
FROM StringDates
```

that is, `STUFF` removes the time zone part and `SUBSTRING` omits the day of week.

Here's the result set:

```
OldDateCol                    NewDateCol
----------------------------  -----------------------
Mon Nov 14 14:52:46 PST 2011  2011-11-14 14:52:46.000
Fri Nov 04 07:50:21 PDT 2011  2011-11-04 07:50:21.000
Thu Dec 01 00:00:00 PST 2011  2011-12-01 00:00:00.000
```

On the other hand, if you are (or might eventually be) using a `datetimeoffset` column for storing the converted values and are interested in preserving the time zone bit of information, you could try the following method:

```
;
WITH StringDates (OldDateCol) AS (
  SELECT 'Mon Nov 14 14:52:46 PST 2011' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Fri Nov 04 07:50:21 PDT 2011' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Thu Dec 01 00:00:00 PST 2011'
),
DatesAndTimeZones AS (
  SELECT
    OldDateCol,
    NewDateCol = CAST(SUBSTRING(STUFF(OldDateCol, 21, 4, ''), 5, 99) AS datetime),
    TimeZoneName = SUBSTRING(OldDateCol, 21, 4)
  FROM StringDates
),
TimeZones (Name, Offset) AS (
  SELECT 'PST', '-08:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'PDT', '-07:00'
)
SELECT
  d.OldDateCol,
  NewDateTimeOffsetCol = TODATETIMEOFFSET(d.NewDateCol, t.Offset)
FROM DatesAndTimeZones d
  INNER JOIN TimeZones t ON d.TimeZoneName = t.Name
```

Here the conversion is done in two steps.

The first step converts the strings to `datetime` values, same as before, and also extracts the time zone names from them.

Basically, those two values would be enough to convert `datetime` to `datetimeoffset`, but SQL Server doesn't recognise time zone *names*, it can only understand *offsets*, in the form of either `+hh:mm` or `-hh:mm`. So you need to replace the names with the corresponding offsets, which can be done with the help of a reference table (the `TimeZones` CTE above plays its part).

So the next (and last) step is joining to the reference table and calling the `TODATETIMEOFFSET()` function to get the final results.

Here's the results of the second query:

```
OldDateCol                    NewDateTimeOffsetCol
----------------------------  ----------------------------------
Mon Nov 14 14:52:46 PST 2011  2011-11-14 14:52:46.000 -08:00
Fri Nov 04 07:50:21 PDT 2011  2011-11-04 07:50:21.000 -07:00
Thu Dec 01 00:00:00 PST 2011  2011-12-01 00:00:00.000 -08:00
```

---

References:

- [datetimeoffset (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx)
- [TODATETIMEOFFSET (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630335.aspx)
- [Date and Time Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this.  Oleg's approach was good, but for some reason, casting it to DATETIME was setting all dates for Jan o1, 2012 to 01-01-1900.  I'll give the above a shot.  I appreciate your descriptive answer as well.